# Prompting for user input, counting string length and reprinting input

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

I am working on an assignment and stuck.  I need to prompt the user to enter a sentence using WriteString and store the input using ReadString. Additionally, I need to count the length of the string and then reprint the users input.  I dont want the code, just a push in the right direction.  I have no problem getting my program to prompt and take the user input, but I'm looking for help counting the length of the string in decimal.

```
.data
String1 BYTE "Enter a sentence", 0
String2 BYTE 50 DUP (?)
String3 BYTE "Decimal length: ", 0
String4 BYTE "Hexidecimal length: ", 0
String5 BYTE "You entered: ", 0

.code
main proc
Exercise1 PROC

mov edx, OFFSET String1 ; move String1 to edx
call WriteString ;prompt user to enter their sentence
mov edx, OFFSET String2 ;array to store input
call ReadString ;store input to edx

;mov ecx, 20
;mov dl, 0 ;use to count length
;how do I loop through String2 to determine its length? 

Exercise1 ENDP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to count the length, `ReadString` returns the number of bytes read in EAX.  http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/readstring.htm

(Also, you have to pass it a max read size in ECX, e.g. `mov ecx, 50-1` before the call.  ReadString needs to know how big your buffer is, so it won't overflow.)

---

If you want to search for the first `0` byte in the string yourself, google `x86 assembly strlen` and take any of the zillions of hits.  Or search here on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I am able to print the decimal length and convert to hexadecimal to print that value as well.   How would I go about reprinting what the user input?

Comment: @MichaelL: With `WriteString`, obviously.  It takes a pointer to a 0-terminated string, which is what you have in your buffer after ReadString returns.